# zip.js loads inflate.js several times

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp, zip.js

I use zip.js to unzip file in browser. But it loads inflate.js many times from client. Each load is successfull (200/304) but why does this happen so many times? How can I load inflate.js once on web page load? This is my usage code:

```
zip.workerScriptsPath = 'lib/';
var br = new zip.Data64URIReader(blob);
zip.createReader(br, function (reader) {
  /// ...
}
```

[image: firebug info]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
zip.useWebWorkers = false;
```

and including

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="lib/inflate.js"></script>
```

statically fixes the problem